# Problem with Triangulation using NetTopologySuite

Tags: c#, wkt, nettopologysuite

I don't have much experience with NetTopologySuite, so any help will be appreciated!

I have a polygon:

```
POLYGON((10 12,10 8,9 8,9 13,10 13,10 15,11 15,11 13,12 13,12 15,14 15,14 13,15 13,15 8,13 8,13 12,12 12,12 9,11 9,11 12,10 12))
```

[image]

and I need to triangulate it, so what I'm doing is basically:

```
var reader = new WKTReader();
var polygon = (Polygon)reader.Read("POLYGON((10 12,10 8,9 8,9 13,10 13,10 15,11 15,11 13,12 13,12 15,14 15,14 13,15 13,15 8,13 8,13 12,12 12,12 9,11 9,11 12,10 12))");
    
var builder = new DelaunayTriangulationBuilder();
    
builder.SetSites(polygon);
var triangles = builder.GetTriangles(GeometryFactory.Default);
```

and if I plot `triangles`, it seems to be not triangulating it properly... I'm not sure if this result is expected or not, but what I need is that the triangulation returns me a list of triangles that will fit exactly inside the input polygon, but instead it's returning:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((9 13, 9 8, 10 12, 9 13)), ((9 13, 10 12, 10 13, 9 13)), ((9 13, 10 13, 10 15, 9 13)), ((10 15, 10 13, 11 13, 10 15)), ((10 15, 11 13, 11 15, 10 15)), ((11 15, 11 13, 12 13, 11 15)), ((11 15, 12 13, 12 15, 11 15)), ((12 15, 12 13, 14 13, 12 15)), ((12 15, 14 13, 14 15, 12 15)), ((14 15, 14 13, 15 13, 14 15)), ((15 13, 14 13, 13 12, 15 13)), ((15 13, 13 12, 15 8, 15 13)), ((13 8, 15 8, 13 12, 13 8)), ((13 8, 13 12, 12 9, 13 8)), ((13 8, 12 9, 10 8, 13 8)), ((10 8, 12 9, 11 9, 10 8)), ((10 8, 11 9, 9 8, 10 8)), ((9 8, 11 9, 10 12, 9 8)), ((10 12, 11 9, 11 12, 10 12)), ((10 12, 11 12, 10 13, 10 12)), ((10 13, 11 12, 11 13, 10 13)), ((11 13, 11 12, 12 12, 11 13)), ((11 13, 12 12, 12 13, 11 13)), ((12 13, 12 12, 13 12, 12 13)), ((12 13, 13 12, 14 13, 12 13)), ((13 12, 12 12, 12 9, 13 12)), ((12 9, 12 12, 11 12, 12 9)), ((12 9, 11 12, 11 9, 12 9)))
```

[image]

So as the second images shows in the marked area, I need the triangles to match that area exactly, like all the others, but it returns me a multipolygon that is missing that part...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

NTS' `DelaunayTriangulation` only takes the `Coordinate`s of the `Geometry`s to build the triangulation. You need to use `ConformingDelauneyTriangulation` to respect boundary lines. Additionally you will need to check for all result triangles if they are contained by the original `Geometry`. A check for the controid will do.